# f:setpropertyactionlistener in datatable always return me the last object

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

f:setpropertyactionlistener inside datatable doesn't give me the current row instead it gives me the last object always..
pls help. thanks!

code.xhtml

```
<p:dataTable id="datatableid"  value="#{updateSiteObj.emsList}" var="pickListObjEMS" >
<p:column headerText="EMS"> 
<p:pickList id="pojoPickListEMSID" value="#{pickListObjEMS.serverList}" var="ems"
itemValue="#{ems}" itemLabel="#{ems}" style="border-color: white!important" onTransfer="ajaxSubmit1()">  
<f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available</f:facet>  
<f:facet name="targetCaption">To be removed</f:facet>  
</p:pickList>
<p:remoteCommand action="# {updateSiteObj.onEMSTransfer}" name="ajaxSubmit1" >
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="# {pickListObjEMS}" target="#{updateSiteObj.tempObj}"/>
</p:remoteCommand> 
</p:column>                                     
</p:dataTable>
```

bean.java

```
 public class UpdateSite {

/** Creates a new instance of UpdateSite */

private List<List<String>> tempEMSList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

private List<serverList> emsList = new ArrayList<serverList>();

private serverList tempObj = new serverList();

public String updateSiteDetails() {
List<String> source = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> target = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String[] str : sg.getEMSDetailsList()) {
                source.add(str[0]);

            }

            DualListModel<String> tempSource = new DualListModel<String>(source, target);
            serverList obj = new serverList();
            obj.setServerList(tempSource);
//here i am adding two objects
            emsList.add(emsobj);
}
public void onEMSTransfer() {

    System.out.print("tempOBJ size:" + tempObj.getServerList().getSource().size() + "=>" + tempObj.getServerList().getTarget().size());

}
```

serverList is a class with a variable of datatype DualListModel. in onEMSTransfer i see the 2nd object is being displayed even when i manipulate first object in picklist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<p:remoteCommand>` generates a JavaScript function on the given `name` in the global scope. The code as you've so far *basically* generates the following (rightclick page and view source to see it with your own eyes):

```html
<script>function ajaxSubmit1() { /* Set pickListObjEMS of row 1. */ }</script>
<script>function ajaxSubmit1() { /* Set pickListObjEMS of row 2. */ }</script>
<script>function ajaxSubmit1() { /* Set pickListObjEMS of row 3. */ }</script>
<script>function ajaxSubmit1() { /* Set pickListObjEMS of row 4. */ }</script>
<script>function ajaxSubmit1() { /* Set pickListObjEMS of row x. */ }</script>
```

You see, it generates multiple JS functions with the same name, overridding each other until the last one! That explains why you're always getting the last item; the last generated JS function is the one being invoked by all rows.

There are at least 2 ways to fix this problem:

1. Give each JS function an unique name. Assuming that your `#{pickListObjEMS}` has an `id` property representing an unique identifier, this should do:

   ```html
   <p:pickList ... onTransfer="ajaxSubmit1_#{pickListObjEMS.id}()">
   ...
   <p:remoteCommand ... name="ajaxSubmit1_#{pickListObjEMS.id}">
   ```
2. Just have only one `<p:remoteCommand>` without `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` outside the table and pass the unique ID (or maybe row index) of the item as request parameter.

   ```html
   <p:dataTable>
       ...
       <p:pickList ... onTransfer="ajaxSubmit1({ id: #{pickListObjEMS.id} })">
       ...
   </p:dataTable>
   <p:remoteCommand ... name="ajaxSubmit1" />
   ```

   You only need to reconstruct the desired `#{pickListObjEMS}` based on the ID which is here passed as request parameter with name `id`.